# cant get form values in django formset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to get the results of a specific form in a formset.  I have tried with a formset and modelformset with no sucess.

**With a FormSet**

My view looks like this:

```
def display(request, pk=None, action='add'):
    customer = get_customer(request)        
    qs = CustomerActivity.objects.filter(customer=customer)


    AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(CustomerActivity, form=ActivityEntryForm, extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AuthorFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid:
            print 'form valied'
            for form in formset:
                 print form.cleaned_data['duration']
            duration = request.POST.get('duration')
            activity = request.POST.get('activity')

            print duration


    else:
        formset = AuthorFormSet(queryset=qs)

    context = {
        'formset':formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'activity/activity.html', context)
```

I get an error:

```
CustomerActivityForm' object has no attribute 'duration'
```

I don't even have a form named CustomerActivityForm, it called ActivityEntryForm:

```
class ActivityEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    duration = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerActivity
        fields = ('duration',)
```

**My regular formset attempt**

Here is my view:

```
def display_2(request, pk=None, action='add'):
    customer = get_customer(request)
    entered_at, day_start, day_end = get_date_query_elements(request)


    qs = CustomerActivity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values()

    ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ActivityEntryForm, extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':


        formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                print form.duration
            pass
    else:
        formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=qs)

    context = {
        'formset':formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'activity/activity.html', context)
```

Here is the form:

```
class ActivityEntryForm(forms.Form):
    duration = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

Here I get the error:

```
ActivityEntryForm' object has no attribute 'duration'
```

How can I get the duration value???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any form, the validated data is in `form.cleaned_data`, which is a dictionary.

```
print form.cleaned_data['duration']
```

This is explained in great detail in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  I added that above and now I get the error:  'CustomerActivityForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'  .  I don't have a form called CustomerActivityForm, do you know where this is generated from?

Comment: It's the automatically generated form inside the formset. But if you're using your first code above, the problem is you need to actually call `is_valid()`; you're missing the parentheses.